# PHP form to send email. How do I maintain values in the form when page is posted back?

Tags: php, forms, email, send

I've created a html / php form based on http://rosstanner.co.uk/2012/11/build-simple-contact-form-html-php-bootstrap/

It successfully validates the form and will send the mail. However, if the form invalidates it returns the user back to the index.php but loses the form values that they entered, which is obviously a bad user experienced.

I tried to use cookies to rectify this, but I've got a feeling its bad practice and it doesn't seem to work on iphone anyway. Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

index.php

```
        <h3><a name="book">Send a booking enquiry</a></h3>

        <p>We are in the process of building a new booking system. In the mean
        time please enter your details below and you will be contacted
        shortly.</p>
        <?php

        $return_form_vals = array();

 if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
 foreach ($_COOKIE['cookie'] as $name => $value) {
  $return_form_vals[htmlspecialchars($name)]=htmlspecialchars($value);
    }

          }
        ?>
        <div class="boostrap form item">
          <form action="contact-send.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
              <input class="textfield" name="your_name" placeholder=
              "Enter your name" value="<?php echo $return_form_vals['your_name'];?>" type="text"><br>
              <input class="textfield" name="phone_number" placeholder=
              "Enter your phone number" type="text" value="<?php echo $return_form_vals['phone_number'];?>"><br>
              <input class="textfield" name="email_address" placeholder=
              "Enter your email address" type="text" value="<?php echo $return_form_vals['email_address'];?>"><br>
              <input class="textfield" name="number_of_people" placeholder=
              "Enter the number of people in your group" type="text" value="<?php echo $return_form_vals['number_of_people'];?>"><br>
              <input id="start_date" class="textfield" type="date" name="start_date" placeholder=
              "Enter the start date for your trip" type="text" value="<?php echo $return_form_vals['start_date'];?>"><br>
               <input id="end_date" class="textfield" type="date" name="end_date" placeholder=
              "Enter the end date for your trip" type="text" value="<?php echo $return_form_vals['end_date'];?>"><br>
              <input name="save" type="hidden" value="contact"> <button class=
              "btn btn-green" type="submit">Send</button>
            </fieldset>
          </form><?php  


                  // check for a successful form post  
                  if (isset($_GET['s'])){print_r($_GET['s']); echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">".$_GET['s']."</div>"; } 

                  // check for a form error  
                  elseif (isset($_GET['e'])) {echo "<div class=\"alert alert-error\">".$_GET['e']."</div>";  }

          ?>
        </div>
```

contact-send.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['save']) || $_POST['save'] != 'contact')
 {
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit;
 }
$your_name = $_POST['your_name'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
$number_of_people = $_POST['number_of_people'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
/*$form_values = array();
$form_values['name'] = $your_name;
$form_values['phone_number'] = $phone_number;
$form_values['start_date'] = $start_date;
$form_values['end_date'] = $end_date;
$form_values['number_of_people'] = $number_of_people;
$form_values['email_address'] = $email_address;*/

setcookie("cookie[your_name]",$_POST['your_name'],time()+10 );
setcookie("cookie[phone_number]",$_POST['phone_number'],time()+10 );
setcookie("cookie[start_date]",$_POST['start_date'],time()+10 );
setcookie("cookie[end_date]",$_POST['end_date'],time()+10 );
setcookie("cookie[number_of_people]",$_POST['number_of_people'],time()+10 );
setcookie("cookie[email_address]",$_POST['email_address'],time()+10 );

if(empty($your_name))
 {
  $error = 'You must enter your name.';
 }
elseif(empty($phone_number))
 {
  $error = 'You must enter a phone number.';
 }
elseif(empty($email_address))
 {
  $error = 'You must enter your email address.';
 }
elseif(empty($start_date))
 {
  $error = 'You must enter a start date.';
 }
 elseif(empty($end_date))
 {
  $error = 'You must enter an end date.';
 }
elseif(empty($number_of_people))
 {
  $error = 'You must enter the number of people.';
 }
// check for a valid email address 
elseif(!preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $email_address))
 {
  $error = 'You must enter a valid email address.';
 }
// check that a message was entered 
if(isset($error))
 {
  header('Location: index.php?e=' . urlencode($error));
  exit;
 }
$email_content .= "Email Address: $email_address\nName: $your_name\Phone Number: $phone_number\nStart Date: $start_date\End Date: $end_date\nNumber of People: $number_of_people\n";
// send the email 
mail("g@gmail.com", "Booking form entry", $email_content);
mail("m@gmail.com", "Booking form entry", $email_content);
// send the user back to the form 
header('Location: index.php?s=' . urlencode('Thank you for your booking enquiry. You will be contacted shortly.'));
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to keep your data in `$_SESSION['name']=$value;` instead of `$_COOKIE`
To prevent submiting wrong data you can use jQuery validate [link](http://plugins.jquery.com/validate) and check user input before submiting form. Then you can notice user to insert valid information to each field. 
example: [link](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/jquery-form-validation-example)

to prevent submiting empty but required form fields you can use HTML attribute `required`
for example

```
<input class="textfield" name="your_name" placeholder=
              "Enter your name" value="<?php echo $return_form_vals['your_name'];?>" type="text" required="required"><br>
```

form will not allow user submit before all required fields are filled

Comment: required="required" is very elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using $_SESSION instead of cookies.
It's as easy as

```
$_SESSION['key'] = $value;
```

But when user comes back again after closing browser form would be cleared.
So consider storing that data in a file or database. You can recognize users by IP.